# Making ElasticSearch show context

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way I can make EalsticSearch show the context of the matches of the queries that I run?

Example:

I have a database with a table with 100 rows. Each row contains a rich text (multiline). 10 of those rows contain the word "foobartest".

Is there a way I can query my ELK for "foobartest" and make it return the surrounding lines of that word? (context)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the `highlight` feature of Elasticsearch. See [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/highlighting-intro.html) documentation for more details.